# Same result in every row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is the code for setting text into the tablerows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    }

    NSString *basis = [chunks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"ONTVANG: %@", basis);

    NSArray *words2 = [basis componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    for (NSString *word2 in words2)
        [chunks2 addObject:word2];

        NSLog(@"Artikelnaam: %@", chunks2);

    NSString *artikelnaamfull = [chunks2 objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *artikelnaam = [artikelnaamfull stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Omschr =" withString:@""];

    cell.textLabel.text = artikelnaam;

    return cell;
}
```

Chucks is:

```
(
"Expnr=672 :Artnr=LB-151          :Omschr = Bord plat 25 cm               :Datum=2-9-2013 0:00:00:Aantal=1:Exclusief=1,61:Inclusief=1,948100:Loca_id=0490",
"Expnr=672 :Artnr=LZ01-0032       :Omschr = Alu. decoboot H31 cm          :Datum=2-9-2013 0:00:00:Aantal=1:Exclusief=12,36:Inclusief=14,955600:Loca_id=0490",
"Expnr=672 :Artnr=LZ02-0006       :Omschr = Windlicht antwhite L          :Datum=2-9-2013 0:00:00:Aantal=1:Exclusief=24,75:Inclusief=29,947500:Loca_id=0490",
"Expnr=672 :Artnr=LZ02-0012       :Omschr = Windlicht antwhite L          :Datum=2-9-2013 0:00:00:Aantal=1:Exclusief=24,75:Inclusief=29,947500:Loca_id=0490",
"Expnr=672 :Artnr=LZ02-0065       :Omschr = Kastje met 3 hangers          :Datum=2-9-2013 0:00:00:Aantal=1:Exclusief=10,70:Inclusief=12,947000:Loca_id=0490",
"Expnr=672 :Artnr=LZ03-0013       :Omschr = Pot RND 34,5x10 zwart         :Datum=2-9-2013 0:00:00:Aantal=1:Exclusief=12,36:Inclusief=14,955600:Loca_id=0490",
"Expnr=672 :Artnr=ML-658          :Omschr = Schaaltje porselein 102x70 mm :Datum=2-9-2013 0:00:00:Aantal=8:Exclusief=5,92:Inclusief=7,163200:Loca_id=0490",
"Expnr=672 :Artnr=ML-817          :Omschr = Beker 180 cc                  :Datum=2-9-2013 0:00:00:Aantal=10:Exclusief=8,30:Inclusief=10,043000:Loca_id=0490",
"Expnr=672 :Artnr=ML-843          :Omschr = Voorraadpot glas 11x11x15 cm  :Datum=2-9-2013 0:00:00:Aantal=1:Exclusief=2,07:Inclusief=2,504700:Loca_id=0490",
"Expnr=672 :Artnr=ML-846          :Omschr = Theelichthouder 8 cm zilver   :Datum=2-9-2013 0:00:00:Aantal=2:Exclusief=2,48:Inclusief=3,000800:Loca_id=0490",
"Totalex= 209",
"Totalin= 263"
```

)

I must have different "Omschr" on different rows.

But i've got on every row the same text. How to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would be helpful to see some of the data you're working with. But other than seeing that, clearly whatever is the object at index 2 in chunks is the same word. Maybe you should log these at every step, because you must be assuming your data is structured in some way that  isn't. Also, I would recommend doing this data massaging in some other method.

Comment: I'll add it now. ADDED!

Comment: what is text you just referred _same_?

Comment: @holex: Bord plat 25 cm

Comment: in that case you will need to replace this part `... = [chunks2 objectAtIndex:2];` with this `... = [words2 objectAtIndex:2];` and problem is solved.

Comment: It works! But he crashes when I scroll down... :(

Comment: that could be a different issue... :)

Comment: From the log: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]`

Comment: yes, because the last two rows are different, and there is no colon (`:`) in the string, so the `works2` array has only one element, and you will try to get the third object which does not exist, it throws you an exception.

Comment: I will create an answer for you, gimme a sec.

Comment: here we go, let me know if something is still not okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the possible solutions would be this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }

    NSString *basis = [chunks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // NSLog(@"ONTVANG: %@", basis);

    NSArray *words2 = [basis componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    for (NSString *word2 in words2) {
        [chunks2 addObject:word2];
    }

    // NSLog(@"Artikelnaam: %@", chunks2);

    NSString *artikelnaamfull = @"(invalid input)";
    if ([words2 count] > 2) artikelnaamfull = [words2 objectAtIndex:2];        
    NSString *artikelnaam = [artikelnaamfull stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Omschr =" withString:@""];

    cell.textLabel.text = artikelnaam;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: HERO OF THE DAY! Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: @MartinR, it was not a contest. :( but it solves his second problem: the crashes as well, and __that is__ why I just created this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

        NSString *basis = [chunks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSLog(@"ONTVANG: %@", basis);

        NSArray *words2 = [basis componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        for (NSString *word2 in words2)
            [chunks2 addObject:word2];

        NSLog(@"Artikelnaam: %@", chunks2);

        NSString *artikelnaamfull = [chunks2 objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *artikelnaam = [artikelnaamfull stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Omschr =" withString:@""];

        cell.textLabel.text = artikelnaam;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Or:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (cell != nil) cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }

    NSString *basis = [chunks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"ONTVANG: %@", basis);

    NSArray *words2 = [basis componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    for (NSString *word2 in words2)
        [chunks2 addObject:word2];

    NSLog(@"Artikelnaam: %@", chunks2);

    NSString *artikelnaamfull = [chunks2 objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *artikelnaam = [artikelnaamfull stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Omschr =" withString:@""];

    cell.textLabel.text = artikelnaam;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I Must have ".Omschr"